# How do I make the Eclipse AST parser work with Java 9?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to use the Eclipse AST parser to parse some Java source code. This code works with Java 8. The AST parser needs `rt.jar` on the classpath to resolve types in code like `class Fo0 {}` since there is an implicit `extends Object` in there. Without `rt.jar` on the classpath passed to the AST parser, I get warnings that "Somewhere, java.lang.Object is used" and type resolution fails.

How do I fix this? I'm using the dependency [org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.13.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.13.0) in my code. Which version supports Java 9?

Answer (score 0):

Update the [JDT Core dependency to 3.16.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.16.0).

Afterwards, the AST will correctly parse code even when `java.lang.Object` isn't in a JAR on the parser's classpath anymore.